# Unset widget tab from media browser programmatically

Tags: 8, forms, media

Need to unset a widget tab from media browser based on the condition of media type supported by the field.

**Media types:** Image and Video.

For example, There is a field which references **image** media type only. When the media browser appears on the form, it displays **create embed** tab as well to embed the videos.

As the field doesn’t reference the **video** media type, need to unset the tab programmatically to help the content author.

I have tried the form alter, but I don't get any information about the media type referenced by the field in the hook.

Comment: Hi, did my answer help you?

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible with some code like this:

```
function MY_MODULE_form_entity_browser_MY_FORM_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {   
  $form['#pre_render'][] = 'MY_MODULE_pre_render';  
}

function MY_MODULE_pre_render($element) {
  kint($element); //Find the tab you want to remove.
  if (...) {
    unset($element['...']);
  }
  return $element;
}
```

Another commonly used solution is to create 2 or 3 media browsers depending on your needs.
So you will have an `image media browser`, a `video media browser` and an `image + video media browser`.

Then you just select which one to use in the field settings.